# How can I save user-created objects to storage in android?

Tags: android, save, storage

In my app, I have flashcard objects that the user creates themselves. Users can create as many flashcards as they want, but when they exit the app and return they need to be able to see the flashcards that they previously created and be able to delete them. I have it set up so that they can create/delete, but if they exit the app they will all delete automatically. What is the best way to save the information for a flashcard? It has at least 3 strings currently, the title, the front and the back.

I looked at a few, but am not sure how I would include all three strings in the saving options that are on the android developer site.

For example shared preferences, looks like you can only save certain settings, but it allows the user to change those settings.
The internal/external storage, although very different throw up the same problem, how to have unlimited number of objects and especially how to save all three strings separately.

This is the internal storage is shown below.

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file"; 
String string = "hello world!";  
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
fos.write(string.getBytes()); 
fos.close();
```

I don't see how you can save multiple number of objects or 3 different strings.

Does anyone see a solution to my problem?

Comment: i think in your case sharedpref will help

Comment: I see why you would say the sharedpref would be best, but if the user is creating the objects, how could i make it save with a different filename for each one? I thought about the filename being the name of the title, but if they have two flashcards with the same title it will only save one of them and discard the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences seem like the simplest way for you to achieve it, and I think you've misunderstood their usage, or confused the name with a 'Preferences' screen, as you can use the SharedPreferences methods to save anything (well, any basic datatype) persistently.

For example, I use it to save my app's JSON data (which might be a decent way for you to go in terms of saving you users' flashcards in a JSONArray).

```
/**
 * Retrieves data from sharedpreferences
 * @param c the application context
 * @param pref the preference to be retrieved
 * @return the stored JSON-formatted String containing the data 
 */
public static String getStoredJSONData(Context c, String pref) {
    if (c != null) {
        SharedPreferences sPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sPrefs.getString(pref, null);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Stores the most recent data into sharedpreferences
 * @param c the application context
 * @param pref the preference to be stored
 * @param policyData the data to be stored
 */
public static void setStoredJSONData(Context c, String pref, String policyData) {
    if (c != null) {
        SharedPreferences sPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(pref, policyData);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Where the string 'pref' is a tag used to refer to that specific piece of data, so for example: "taylor.matt.data1" would refer to a piece of data and could be used to retrieve or store it from SharedPreferences

Comment: let me digest what this says:)

Comment: so to use your example, pref would be either title, front or back correct? then how would i specify different objects?

Comment: the only reason i think i have a problem is because the user can create an unlimited number of objects. and they all need to be saved. other than that, saving an object would seem pretty straightforward

Comment: As you say, you could indeed have a preference for each one, or you could alternatively just store all of your user's data in a single preference using JSON

Comment: Like so: [{"title":"mycard","front":"front_data1","back":"back_data1"},
{"title":"mycard2","front":"front_data2", "back":"back_data2"},
{"title":"mycard3","front":"front_data3", "back":"back_data3"}]

Comment: If you're not sure about how JSON works, there are some great tutorials online, but copy and paste my above comment into http://json.parser.online.fr/ to see how it's structured